# Spartacus 2211 SSR

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Just try to start some project with enabled SSR at SAP Composable Storefront 2211. Looks like cause of Angular 17 upgrade SSR part was changed. I was struggling how to start serve and to see working SSR, seems like documentation not updated.

Can somebody suggest how to do this, as it not works the same as in previous versions?

Comment: What is your actually problem? I did an upgrade to the latest version and it also updated  my SSR configuration. Build and serve commands stayed the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

server.ts changed. Please check those line

```
import { dirname, join, resolve } from 'node:path';
const indexHtml = join(serverDistFolder, 'index.server.html');
```